# Calling an onclick function in for loop with a table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filesaver.js

i am trying to have a button in a table column and when its clicked, i want to invoke a service with values from that row.
can someone please help achieve this.

```
  function setResponseData(data, length) {
        var insertHTML = "<TR class=\"heading\"><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;TIMESTAMP&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;OPERATION&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TYPE&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;LOG &nbsp;&nbsp;LEVEL&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;VERSION&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;TYPE&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;SESSIONID&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;PIECEID&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;SHIPMENTID&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;SYSTEM &nbsp;ORIGIN&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;SYSTEM &nbsp;DESTINATION&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;SYSTEM &nbsp;DATAORIGIN&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;DIRECT &nbsp;INJECTION &nbsp;ORGANISATION&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;PRODUCT&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;STATUS&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;STATUS&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;CODE&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;STATUS MESSAGE&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;NODENAME&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;PIECENUMBER&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;TOTALPIECES&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;SYSTEMNAME&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;INSERT &nbsp;&nbsp;TIMESTAMP&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;EVENT &nbsp;CODE&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;CUSTOMERID&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD><TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;&nbsp;PAYLOAD&nbsp;&nbsp;</TD></TR>";
        //var PayloadBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var audit = data.results[i];
            //var PayloadBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            //PayloadBtn.innerHTML = audit.PAYLOAD;
            
            
            
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                insertHTML += "<TR style='background-color:#F0F0E0'>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TR style='background-color:#E0E0C0'>";
            }


            if (Boolean(audit.TIMESTAMP)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.TIMESTAMP + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.OPERATIONTYPE)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.OPERATIONTYPE + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.LOGLEVEL)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.LOGLEVEL + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.VERSION)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.VERSION + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.TYPE)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.TYPE + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.SESSIONID)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.SESSIONID + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.PIECEID)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.PIECEID + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.SHIPMENTID)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.SHIPMENTID + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.SYSTEMORIGIN)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.SYSTEMORIGIN + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.SYSTEM_DESTINATION)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.SYSTEM_DESTINATION + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.SYSTEMDATAORIGIN)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.SYSTEMDATAORIGIN + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
             if (Boolean(audit.DIRECT_INJECTION_ORGANISATION)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.DIRECT_INJECTION_ORGANISATION + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.PRODUCT)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.PRODUCT + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.STATUS)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.STATUS + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.STATUS_CODE)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.STATUS_CODE + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.STATUS_MESSAGE)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.STATUS_MESSAGE + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.NODE_NAME)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.NODE_NAME + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.PIECENUMBER)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.PIECENUMBER + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.TOTALPIECES)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.TOTALPIECES + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.SYSTEM_NAME)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.SYSTEM_NAME + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.INSERT_TIMESTAMP)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.INSERT_TIMESTAMP + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.EVENT_CODE)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.EVENT_CODE + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.CUSTOMERID)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;" + audit.CUSTOMERID + "&nbsp;</TD>";
            } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
            if (Boolean(audit.PAYLOAD)) {
                insertHTML += "<TD><input class='myclass' type='button' value='Download' onclick =getPayload(${data.results[i]})/></TD>";
           } else {
                insertHTML += "<TD align=\"center\">&nbsp;</TD>";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("contentTable").innerHTML = insertHTML;
    }
```

function getPayload(audit) {

```
        var param = "?";
        var flag = "false";
        if (audit.VERSION != "" && audit.SESSIONID!= "" && audit.SHIPMENTID!="" && audit.SYSTEM_NAME!="" && audit.TYPE!="") {
        
            param += "shipmentId=" + audit.SHIPMENTID;
            param += "version=" + audit.VERSION;
            param += "sessionId=" +audit.SESSIONID;
            param += "systemName=" + audit.SYSTEM_NAME;
            param += "messageType=" + audit.TYPE;
            param += "operationType=" + audit.OPERATIONTYPE;
            flag = "true";
        }

        var err = document.getElementById("errorContent");
        err.style.display = "none";

        var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
       
        // We setup our request
        XHR.open("GET", "/restv2/getPayloadml" + param);
```

I want to invoke the function getPayload when the download button is clicked, but its not calling that function.

My download button is in a for loop and are displayed in a table column.
when i click a particuar button, i want that row values to be sent to the function getPayload so i am giving as onclick =getPayload(${data.results[i]. am doing something wrong here that the function is not  called.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV4Z2.png)

Comment: If you wan to pass two parameters to that function, then you need to modify the `onclick=getdata(${data.results[i]})` part accordingly. (Don't ask me with what exactly, we don't know what your `data` variable contains.)

Comment: Long time I have seen upper case HTML, maybe you should check your HTML if it's valid: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you're asking.  It looks like you're currently invoking your `getdata` function and passing it one value, and asking how to pass it two values.  Have you tried passing it two values?  What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: Please see my updated question and let me know if its clear

Comment: @David  Could you please check and help on  this

Comment: @TAHASEEN: Now is a good time to start using your browser’s debugging tools. Are there any errors at all on the browser console? What is the resulting HTML of these buttons that you’re adding to the page?

Answer (score 0):

In your browser's DOM explorer, examine the result of this string literal:

```
"<TD><input class='myclass' type='button' value='Download' onclick =getPayload(${data.results[i]})/></TD>"
```

You'll find it to be, literally, this:

```
<TD><input class='myclass' type='button' value='Download' onclick =getPayload(${data.results[i]})/></TD>
```

Which is incorrect in that:

1. There are no quotes around the `onclick` attribute value.
2. `${data.results[i]}` is a syntax error.

It looks like you're trying to use template literals.  You should also be using double-quotes around attribute values, not single-quotes.  So the string literal (template literal) would be something like this:

```
`<TD><input class="myclass" type="button" value="Download" onclick ="getPayload(${data.results[i]})" /></TD>`
```

Note the use of back-ticks to wrap the literal and the use of double-quotes around attribute values.  Browsers are pretty lenient about allowing single-quotes, but in general when your code isn't doing what you expect then the *first* thing to do is ensure that it's at least technically syntactically correct.